# Build only `lib` target

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to build a dynamic link library (`dll`).
My `Cargo.toml` currently looks like this:

```
[package]
name = "sample"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["author"]

[lib]
name = "main"
crate-type = ["dylib"]

[dependencies]
```

I use VS Code with the `RustyCode` plugin as my IDE on windows.
When I run the build command this builds into a `sample.exe` and `main.dll`.
I know I can run `cargo build --lib` to only build my `lib` target but I dont have access to this command inside VS Code (afaik).
Is there anyway to specify that I only want to build the `lib` target in my `Cargo.toml` file so I can use the VS Code build command which runs `cargo build`/`cargo run`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cargo builds files using convention over configuration approach. When it finds a `main.rs` it builds an executable, and when it encounters `lib.rs` it expects to build a library.

Calling your lib `main` managed to confuse Cargo. The only solution I managed to find is to either change name of your crate from `name = "main"` to `name = "foo"` (and then rename your `main.rs` into `foo.rs`) or to change its name to `lib.rs`, as you did.

Comment: That answer is way more informative than mine, thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Just figured it: Rename the `src/main.rs` to `src/lib.rs` and it only builds the `lib` target!